# extract PSComputerName for invoke command

Tags: windows, powershell, loops, object, remote-server

Hello I am working on a Powershell script that checks on remote PC if any recent update fail generate a txt file to send via email like a daily report here is the script:

```html
$machines = Get-Content “Q:\Users\E\servers2.txt”
$outputfile = 'Q:\Users\E\Processes.dat'

foreach ( $computer in $machines){
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
function Convert-WuaResultCodeToName
{
param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int] $ResultCode)
$Result = $ResultCode
switch($ResultCode)
{2{$Result = "Succeeded"}3{$Result = "Succeeded With Errors"}4{$Result = "Failed"}}
return $Result}
function Get-WuaHistory
{
$session = (New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session')
$history = $session.QueryHistory("",0,22) | ForEach-Object {
$Result = Convert-WuaResultCodeToName -ResultCode $_.ResultCode
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $Result -Name Result
$Product = $_.Categories | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'Product'} | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateId -Name UpdateId
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.UpdateIdentity.RevisionNumber -Name RevisionNumber
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $Product -Name Product -PassThru
Write-Output $_
}
$history | Where-Object {$_.title} | Select-Object @{Name='psComputerName';Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}},Result,Date,Title,Product
}


$fileout = @()
$date = Get-Date -format dd.MM.yy
$time = Get-Date -format HH:mm
$compa = (Get-Date).AddHours(-12)


$result = Get-WuaHistory |Select-Object -Unique -Property PSComputerName,Result,Date,Title 
foreach ($item in $result){
    if ($item.Result -like 'Failed'-and $item.Date -gt $compa){
        $outputLine = $item.PSComputerName + "|" + $date + " " + $time + "|Recent_update_fail|NONE|WARNING|" + $item.Title +" on " + $item.Date + " Status: " + $item.Result
        $fileout += $outputLine
        }
   else {
        $outputLine = $item.PSComputerName + "|" + $date + " " + $time + "|Recent_update_fail|NONE|OK|" + $item.Title +" on " + $item.Date + " Status: " + $item.Result
        $fileout += $outputLine
        }
}
}
Clear-Content "$outputfile"
Start-sleep 1
Add-Content "$outputfile" $fileout
$stream = [IO.File]::OpenWrite($outputfile)
                $stream.Close()
                $stream.Dispose()
}
```

So far the script works it gets all the failed updates and generates a string but the problem is basically inside the string the pc name is missing the $item.PSComputerName dot returns the name of the remote computer I tried different combinations or casting string out of the $result but the computer name is still empty

Thanks in advance for your time

Edit 1 Following the solution of @Toni now the script work and pick up the servers name but now I am struggling to output the file I check a test output on the console and is fine and at the moment the output statement used generates a file but unfortunately is an empty file how can I resolve?

Comment: Try : [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("192.168.X.X")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to access the property `psComputerName` from the elements stored in the array `$history`. But those elements do not have a property called pscomputername, the available properties are:

```
$history[0] | gm | ?{$_.membertype -match 'property'}

Name                MemberType   Definition
----                ----------   ----------
Product             NoteProperty System.String Product=Microsoft Defender Antivirus
Result              NoteProperty object Result=null
RevisionNumber      NoteProperty int RevisionNumber=200
UpdateId            NoteProperty string UpdateId=df8b6e72-7b5a-4b4a-ac52-3562fe306501
Categories          Property     ICategoryCollection Categories () {get}
ClientApplicationID Property     string ClientApplicationID () {get}
Date                Property     Date Date () {get}
Description         Property     string Description () {get}
HResult             Property     int HResult () {get}
Operation           Property     tagUpdateOperation Operation () {get}
ResultCode          Property     OperationResultCode ResultCode () {get}
ServerSelection     Property     ServerSelection ServerSelection () {get}
ServiceID           Property     string ServiceID () {get}
SupportUrl          Property     string SupportUrl () {get}
Title               Property     string Title () {get}
UninstallationNotes Property     string UninstallationNotes () {get}
UninstallationSteps Property     IStringCollection UninstallationSteps () {get}
UnmappedResultCode  Property     int UnmappedResultCode () {get}
UpdateIdentity      Property     IUpdateIdentity UpdateIdentity () {get}
```

To include the computerName you can used calculated property:

```
$history | Where-Object {$_.title} | Select-Object @{Name='psComputerName';Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}},Result,Date,Title,Product
```

Comment: hello Toni I tried your solution and it worked!

Comment: I also amend the script in the post but now I have  some issues to output the file the output statement seams working but  the file is empty

Comment: within you function you must return the result, e.g. return $history. once you call the function you must store the value returned in a variable which you can later use to export the data, e.g. $result = Get-WuaHistory -> $result | export-csv

Comment: Sorry @Toni I  lost you during the function I store the result formatted as string in $fileout in the second loop and if I try recall the variable in the same loop is ok is only in the final loop that is missing or the output in the same loop